# Background image isn't responsive at Nuxt.js

Tags: css, vue.js, background-image, nuxt.js

I recently started developing a Nuxt app and it failed at CSS side at very early phases. To my problem, which seems very repetitive at this field, it's responsive background. So far everything seemed fine unless opening at mobile web browser.

I want to put an image at background and every content/vue component etc slides in front of it. Here is what I tried so far:

I checked at Chrome web (with extending and stretching all the way up and down and seemed right) , Chrome developer tools (various mobile responsiveness also passed and had seen bg-image covers all the screen)
.
But; I opened the website on my phone and asked some of my friends to check that, all send the same problem, it wasn't stretching (covering) at mobile.

https://ibb.co/k129BrQ
this one with no padding at index.vue by mobile browser

https://ibb.co/PD5Sfyc
this one with 1000px padding-top at index.vue by mobile browser

https://ibb.co/PD5Sfyc
this one with 1500px padding-top at index.vue but chrome dev tools at iphone X settings (also what i expected and wanted to see)

-website

--assets

---css

----main.css

```
body {
    background: url('../img/background.jpg') no-repeat fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;   
}
```

---layouts

----default.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <nuxt />
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    export default {

    }
</script>
```

---pages

----index.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing.</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  layout: 'default'
}
</script>
```

I did expected to see all screen of mobile browser covered by image but i realized this;
It covers the content that app created, if content cant reach the screens end, it wont render as i expected.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a problem of nuxt, but as you said, rather a css problem.
I assume that your container, which is defined by the size of the content is not big enough to stretch vertically over your screen.
So you may have to apply some extra css to do so:

```
.container-which-contains-bg {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Does this achieve, what you want?

If so, you have to be aware of `vh` causing some trouble on safari iOS. There you maybe would have to go for `min-height: 100%;` and also set all your wrappers to have a height of 100%. (for example `body`, `head` and whatever else is wrapping your image-container div).

Edit:
Sorry in your case you are applying the style to the `body`.
So you could use `body { min-height: 100vh; }` or `body { height: 100%; }` and set your `html { height: 100%; }` as well. (I am not sure if body and head have to be `min-height: 100%;` or `height: 100%;`. Just try it...